# How to correctly write http response so as to use XHR progress event listener

Tags: javascript, http, http-headers, xmlhttprequest, httpresponse

I would like to use XHR object's "progress" event to get the progress of download.

Here's example code from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/using_xmlhttprequest#Monitoring_progress)

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();

req.addEventListener("progress", updateProgress, false);
req.addEventListener("load", transferComplete, false);
req.addEventListener("error", transferFailed, false);
req.addEventListener("abort", transferCanceled, false);

req.open();

...

// progress on transfers from the server to the client (downloads)
function updateProgress(evt) {
  if (evt.lengthComputable) {
    var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
    ...
  } else {
    // Unable to compute progress information since the total size is unknown
  }
}

function transferComplete(evt) {
  alert("The transfer is complete.");
}

function transferFailed(evt) {
  alert("An error occurred while transferring the file.");
}

function transferCanceled(evt) {
  alert("The transfer has been canceled by the user.");
}
```

I've written similar code, but `lengthComputable` field of the progress event turns out to be false. The `loaded` field is some finite value, but `total` is set to zero.

From the comment in the code example above, I can see that the browser doesn't get enough information in the HTTP response to calculate a meaningful download progress.

What is the correct way to write the response to make this work? The response I see in my testing has `Transfer-encoding: chunked` and `Content-Length: 8`. I am generating it from Tornado Web server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the [chunked transfer encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding), the total length of the response is not indicated by the server, and therefore not known to the client in advance.

You can try two things.

- Either disable chunked transfer encoding in favor of the normal approach with `Content-Length`. This is what the Progress Events specification [requires](http://www.w3.org/TR/progress-events/#firing-events-using-the-progressevent-interface-for-http). But I don’t know if/how this is possible with Tornado.
- Or, include total length in a custom response header like `X-Total-Length`. Then, use code like this to determine your percentage:

  ```
  function updateProgress(evt) {
    var total = evt.lengthComputable ?
                evt.total : parseInt(req.getResponseHeader('X-Total-Length'));
    if (total) {
      var percentComplete = evt.loaded / total;
      // ...
    }
  }
  ```

Comment: The second trick worked kinda. I needed to do this because of gzip compression. gzip always made lengthComputable == false, the Content-Length header is correct for the compressed size and allows the page to load. I had to approximate the compression level and adjust the total accordingly. Hopefully there is a better way to do this.